# Unable to set <iframe> srcdoc value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do here is dynamically add and display content as HTML inside an iframe by using jquery to set the `srcdoc` attribute on the click of a button. Nothing happens though when I click on the button:

Strangely enough, when I replace `$("#myFrame").srcdoc` with `document.getElementById("myFrame)` the code works as intended. That further baffles me.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <title> Jquery Project - Practice </title>
        
        <script type = "text/javascript" src ="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> </script>
        
        <link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel ="stylesheet">
        
        <script src = "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            
            html, body {
                font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            
            div, textarea {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            
            * {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            
            #divOne {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background-color:aliceblue;
            }
             
        </style>
             
    </head>
    
    <body> 
        
        <div id="divOne">
            
            <iframe id ="myFrame"></iframe>
            
            <button id = "click"> Click Me! </button>
            
        </div>
        
        <script type ="text/javascript">
            
            
            $(document).ready(function() {
                
                $("#myFrame").css({
                    "height":"300px",
                    "width":"300px",
                    "margin":"200px",
                    "background-color":"bisque"
                });
                
                $("#click").click(function() {
                    
                    $("#myFrame").srcdoc = "<p>Hello World!</p>" ;
                    //alert("clicked");
                
                });
                
            });
                
                   
        </script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Usually jquery references in this form $("#myFrame") ... create a collection and you need to use array notation to deal with elements in that collection, like this -  $("#myFrame")[0].srcdoc = "<p>Hello World!</p>";  -- failing in that, it might also be better to try $("#myFrame").prop('srcdoc','<p>Hello World!</p>');

Answer (score 3):

Set it by using `.attr()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myFrame").css({
    "height": "300px",
    "width": "300px",
    "margin": "200px",
    "background-color": "bisque"
  });

  $("#click").click(function() {
    $("#myFrame").attr("srcdoc", "<p>Hello World!</p>");
  });
  
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div,
textarea {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#divOne {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne">
  <iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
  <button id="click"> Click Me! </button>
</div>
```